# Spatial temporal kriging

Tags: r, gstat, kriging

I'm working on rainfall data. I have grid of rainfall points of 1 square kilometer with time step of 10 minutes. I want interpolate those point at every time step. also I want to check the temporal correlation of my rainfall points. The program I'm using is R. But I'm stuck I cant find my way forward...! Here is a link of my single rainfall data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B430nIYqp_1OLXZia2htbGRGWTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

The CRAN taskview for spatial temporal analysis suggests packages to use.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SpatioTemporal.html

I see that you have tagged gstat, so the gstat way might be of interest to you.

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gstat/vignettes/st.pdf

Does this help?